# Filter Dataframe rows for Maptype Keys

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame with a MapType column and I want to filter rows that do not contain a certain key.

For example here is my data:

```
val ds = Seq(
     |   (1, Map("foo" -> (1, "a"), "bar" -> (2, "b"))),
     |   (2, Map("foo" -> (3, "c"))),
     |   (3, Map("bar" -> (4, "d")))
     | ).toDF("id", "alpha")
```

How would I filter for only rows that contain "bar" as a key? What if I want to filter for rows that contain "bar" AND their value is not null?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a filter where your map contains the key "bar" as a key with a non-null value:

```
dataFrame.filter(col("alpha").getItem("bar").isNotNull)
```